# Как именно использовать (хранить) IP в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

У меня изначально в MySQL IP-адреса были в `varchar`'e, но в интернете пишут, что для хранения IP-адресов лучше всего использовать `INT` (`UNSIGNED`). Нашёл информацию про некие функции типа `INNET_NTOA()`, `INNET_ATON()` это в MySQL, а в php `ip2long()`. 
Так вот, использую функцию PHP `ip2long()`, соответственно в БД `INT (11) UNSIGNED`.

Но теперь IP преобразовался в такое: 396157915, то есть возвращает числа без точек. Собственно вопрос, как это привести в нормальный вид?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.long2ip.php

Comment: Для преобразования из числа в адрес - INET_NTOA - сразу в запросе к базе пишите

Comment: "Для преобразования из числа в адрес - INET_NTOA - сразу в запросе к базе пишите " что именно имеете ввиду, уточните, пожалуйста?

Comment: Вы делаете не так. Вы делаете ip2long при записи, а надо ещё long2ip при чтении.

Comment: Написал свой код, можете дать пример, пожалуйста? Что-то никак не пойму все это.

Answer (score 1):

выполните этот запрос
select INET_ATON('8.8.8.8'), INET_NTOA(134744072)

Comment: Вот пример моего кода: $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE ip = '". $ip ."'")->fetch_row()) { где $ip пишу так $ip = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ip));

Comment: честно говоря я не знаю php. если вы в консоли mysql выполните код который я привел выше то увидите что он работает. возможно вам не стоит заморачиваться с функциями php а использовать функционал mysql напрямую

Comment: Хорошо, тогда можете привести пример кода на MySQLi, но не запрос к бд через консоль. Просто у меня там не только один IP, их куча, собственно из перемены $ip Айпи пользователей.

Comment: Так я выше и привел пример кода. Смотрите вам нужно сделать insert в таблицу - то тогда по идее вы пишите так:  $mysqli->query("insert into table (ip, nameserver) values ( INET_ATON('8.8.8.8'), 'http://site.com')"). Теперь вам нужна выборка, то пишите уже как то так: $mysqli->query("SELECT INET_NTOA(ip), nameserver FROM table'"). Замечу что так передавать данные напрямую в sql запросы не безопасно.

Comment: Решил проблему, как выше сказали, оказывается еще long2ip сделать при чтении данных. Спасибо Владу, ну и естественно Вам за помощь. Только вот такой вопрос, достаточно ли ip2long() или же все же вот так нужно $ip = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ip)); подскажите, буду рад. :)

Comment: вы поймите - одна функция из строки делает число а другая из числа строку, если в бд у вас хранится число то вам надо строку конвертировать в число и наоборот